# Estou com um problema de lógica para filtrar o cadastro e edição de meu agendamento de consulta

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, lógica

Estou Utilizando o componente Schedule do Primefaces(6.2)
Meu projeto utiliza: 
Postgres, Hibernate, JSF.

Com o código desta maneira eu consigo cadastrar um novo agendamento e não consigo adicionar um novo agendamento para o mesmo médico no mesmo dataInicio e dataFim de um agendamento.
(O objetivo era esse)

Problema 1: 
O problema atual é que quando vou fazer a edição do mesmo agendamento não consigo salvar, pois é entendido pelo código que estou tentando salvar outro agendamento no mesmo dataInicio e dataFim de um agendamento já existente!

Problema 2: Ao editar um agendamento já criado e tentar salva-lo o registro é duplicado, o registro antes da edição se mantém e o novo é salvo alterado.
Classe Evento(Agendamento)

```
/**
 * @author Humberto
 *
 */

@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "evento")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "evento_seq", sequenceName = "evento_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class Evento  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1089332436469136104L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "evento_seq")
        private Long id;
        private String titulo;

        private Date dataInicio;
        private Date dataFim;
        private boolean diaInteiro;
        private TipoEvento tipoEvento;
        private String descricao;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn()
        private Paciente paciente;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn()
        private Medico medico;


        public Evento() {
            this.tipoEvento = TipoEvento.CONSULTA;
            this.titulo = "";
            this.diaInteiro = false;
        }

        public Evento(Long id,
                String titulo, 
                Date dataInicio, 
                Date dataFim, 
                boolean diaInteiro, 
                TipoEvento tipoEvento,
                String descricao,
                Paciente paciente,
                Medico medico)
        {

            this.id = id;
            this.titulo = titulo;
            this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
            this.dataFim = dataFim;
            this.diaInteiro = diaInteiro;
            this.tipoEvento = tipoEvento;
            this.setDescricao(descricao);
            this.paciente = paciente;
            this.medico =  medico;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitulo() {
            return titulo;
        }

        public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
            this.titulo = titulo;
        }

        public Date getDataInicio() {
            return dataInicio;
        }

        public void setDataInicio(Date dataInicio)  {
            //Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance() ;
          //  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8) ;
            //calendar.set(Calendar);

            this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
        }

        public Date getDataFim() {
            return dataFim;
        }

        public void setDataFim(Date dataFim) {
            this.dataFim = dataFim;
        }

        public boolean isDiaInteiro() {
            return diaInteiro;
        }

        public void setDiaInteiro(boolean diaInteiro) {
            this.diaInteiro = diaInteiro;
        }

        public TipoEvento getTipoEvento() {
            return tipoEvento;
        }

        public void setTipoEvento(TipoEvento tipoEvento) {
            this.tipoEvento = tipoEvento;
        }

        public Medico getMedico() {
            return medico;
        }

        public void setMedico(Medico medico) {
            this.medico = medico;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 3;
            hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final Evento other = (Evento) obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public Paciente getPaciente() {
            return paciente;
        }

        public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
            this.paciente = paciente;
        }

        public String getDescricao() {
            return descricao;
        }

        public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }


    }
```

ScheduleBean

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "scheduleBean")
    @Controller
    @Scope(value = "session")
    public class ScheduleBean extends BeanManagedViewAbstract {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private ScheduleModel model;
        private Evento evento;
        private ScheduleEvent event;
        private List<ScheduleEvent> scheduleEvents;
        private Date dataInicioSelecionada;
        private Date dataFimSelecionada;

        Date dataAtual = new Date();

        private CarregamentoLazyListForObjeto<Evento> list = new CarregamentoLazyListForObjeto<Evento>();

        @Autowired
        private EventoController eventoController;

        @Autowired
        private PacienteController pacienteController;

        @Autowired
        private MedicoController medicoController;

        public ScheduleBean() {
            event = new CustomScheduleEvent();
            model = new DefaultScheduleModel();

            evento = new Evento();
        }

        @Override
        public StreamedContent getArquivoReport() throws Exception {
            super.setNomeRelatorioJasper("report_evento");
            super.setNomeRelatorioSaida("report_evento");
            super.setListDataBeanCollectionReport(eventoController.findList(getClassImp()));
            return super.getArquivoReport();
        }

        // LISTA DE PACIENTES
        public List<SelectItem> getPacientes() throws Exception {
            return pacienteController.getListPacientes();
        }

        // LISTA DE MEDICOS
        public List<SelectItem> getMedicos() throws Exception {
            return medicoController.getListMedicos();
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() throws Exception {

            if (this.model != null) {
                List<Evento> eventos = this.eventoController.listarEventos();
                // List<Evento> eventos = this.eventoDAO.listarTodos();
                if (this.scheduleEvents == null) {
                    this.scheduleEvents = new ArrayList<ScheduleEvent>();
                }
                for (Evento eventoAtual : eventos) { // lista que popula os eventos e inseri
                    ScheduleEvent newEvent = new CustomScheduleEvent(eventoAtual.getTitulo(), eventoAtual.getDataInicio(),
                            eventoAtual.getDataFim(), eventoAtual.getTipoEvento().getCss(), eventoAtual.isDiaInteiro(),
                            eventoAtual.getDescricao(), eventoAtual.getMedico(), eventoAtual.getPaciente(), eventoAtual);
                    if (!this.scheduleEvents.contains(newEvent)) {
                        newEvent.setId(eventoAtual.getId().toString());
                        this.scheduleEvents.add(newEvent);
                        this.model.addEvent(newEvent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean validarMedico() throws Exception {

    String[] param = new String[] {"idMedico", "dataInicio", "dataFim","eventoId"};
    String hql ="FROM Evento e WHERE e.medico.idMedico = "
            + ":idMedico AND (e.dataInicio BETWEEN :dataInicio AND :dataFim "
            + "OR e.dataFim BETWEEN :dataInicio AND :dataFim) AND (e.id = :eventoId AND :eventoId IS NOT NULL)";

    List<Evento> lista = eventoController.findListByQueryDinamica(
            hql, Arrays.asList(param) , evento.getMedico().getIdMedico(), evento.getDataInicio(), evento.getDataFim(),evento.getId());
    //novo
    if (evento.getId() == null && !lista.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
        //se for igual as datas e lista vier completa
        // vindo completa quer dizer que há um agendamento gravado
    }else if((this.dataInicioSelecionada.compareTo(evento.getDataInicio()) != 0 ||
              this.dataFimSelecionada.compareTo(evento.getDataFim()) !=0) 
            &&  !lista.isEmpty()){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}

    public void salvar() throws Exception {
        // salva o construtor que implementa a interface do Schedule com os atributos.
        ScheduleEvent newEvent = new CustomScheduleEvent(this.evento.getTitulo(), this.evento.getDataInicio(),
                this.evento.getDataFim(), this.evento.getTipoEvento().getCss(), this.evento.isDiaInteiro(),
                this.evento.getDescricao(), this.evento.getMedico(), this.evento.getPaciente(), this.evento);

        if (evento.getDataInicio().before(evento.getDataFim()) && validarMedico()) {

            if (evento.getId() == null) {
                model.addEvent(newEvent);
            } else {
                newEvent.setId(event.getId());
                model.updateEvent(newEvent);
            }
            eventoController.merge(evento);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Agendamento Salvo",
                    "Agendamento para:  " + evento.getTitulo());
            addMessage(message);
        }else {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Já existe um médico cadastrado CAIU NO ELSE",
                    "" );
            addMessage(message);
        }
    }

    public void remover() throws Exception {
    try{
        eventoController.delete(evento);
        model.deleteEvent(event);
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Agendamento Removido",
                "Agendamento Removido :" + evento.getTitulo());
        addMessage(message);
    }catch (Exception e) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Impossivel remover",
                "Há dependencias:" + evento.getTitulo());
        addMessage(message);
    }


}

    // AO SALVAR SELEÇÃO DE UMA AGENDAMENTO
    public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        this.evento = new Evento();
        Date dataSelecionada = (Date) selectEvent.getObject();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        DateTime dataSelecionadaJoda = new DateTime(dataSelecionada.getTime());
        this.evento.setDataInicio(dataSelecionada);
        // Adiciona 30min por consulta
        //this.evento.setDataFim(dataSelecionadaJoda.plusMinutes(30).toDate());
    }

    // EVENTO DE SELEÇÃO DOS HORARIOS AGENDADOS
    public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = (CustomScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
        this.evento = (Evento) event.getData();
        this.dataInicioSelecionada = this.evento.getDataInicio();
        this.dataFimSelecionada = this.evento.getDataFim();
    }

    // EVENTO QUE PERMITE REDIMENSIONAR HORARIOS
    public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Evento Redimensionado",
                "Dia:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Horário:" + event.getMinuteDelta());
        addMessage(message);
    }

    // EVENTO QUE PERMITE MOVER HORARIOS SELECIONADOS
    public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
        /*
         * if(evento.getDataInicio().getTime() <= evento.getDataFim().getTime()){
         * 
         * try{ eventoController.merge(evento); }catch(Exception ex){
         * FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new
         * FacesMessage("Erro ao salvar trabalho", "Erro:" + ex.getMessage())); } evento
         * = new Evento(); }else{ FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new
         * FacesMessage("Data do começo do evento não pode ser maior que a do final",
         * "")); }
         */

        // FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event
        // moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" +
        // event.getMinuteDelta());

        // addMessage(message);
    }

    private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public TipoEvento[] getTiposEventos() {
        return TipoEvento.values();
    }

    // GETTERS E SETTERS

    public List<ScheduleEvent> getScheduleEvents() {
        return scheduleEvents;
    }

    public void setScheduleEvents(List<ScheduleEvent> scheduleEvents) {
        this.scheduleEvents = scheduleEvents;
    }

    public Date getDataAtual() {
        return dataAtual;
    }

    public void setDataAtual(Date dataAtual) {
        // Pega somente a data para passar para data minima do calendario
        LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate();
        dataAtual = localDate.toDate();

        this.dataAtual = dataAtual;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<Evento> getClassImp() {
        return Evento.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected InterfaceCrud<Evento> getController() {
        return eventoController;
    }

    @Override
    public void consultarEntidade() throws Exception {
        evento = new Evento();
        list.clean();
        list.setTotalRegistroConsulta(super.totalRegistroConsulta(), super.getSqlLazyQuery());

    }

    @Override
    public String condicaoAndParaPesquisa() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    public ScheduleModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(ScheduleModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Evento getEvento() {
        return evento;
    }

    public void setEvento(Evento evento) {
        this.evento = evento;
    }

    public CarregamentoLazyListForObjeto<Evento> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(CarregamentoLazyListForObjeto<Evento> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Opa, pelo que eu vi, existem varios pontos onde voce faz o new Evento(). Se voce colocar o breakpoint aqui: if (evento.getId() == null)  .. . dentro do salvar, voce tem registro dom o id preenchido ou sempre novo?

Comment: Ele vem null sempre, retirei o new Evento na declaração de variáveis e mantive no construtor somente.
Após a mudança ele traz preenchido o id

Comment: Entao, na sua validacao, agora voce tem que tentar procurar para o mesmo medico, mesmo dia e horario, um evento de id diferente do selecionado (em caso de edicao) ou qualquer ID em caso de novo agendamento.

Comment: Entendi estou tentando implementar, porém ainda se sucesso, teria algum exemplo ?

Comment: Adiciona na sua query: " AND (:eventoId IS NOT NULL AND e.id = :eventoId) " e passa o e.getId() como parametro pro seu metodo que executa a query dinamica.

Comment: Alterei para (e.id = :eventoId AND :eventoId IS NOT NULL) pois estava dando erro de passagem de argumento na query.
Ao fazer mais teste verifiquei que consigo agendar entre a data inicio e data fim de um mesmo médico.
Exemplo: Tenho no bd cadastrado inicio: 21/01/2019 18:00 fim 21/01/2019 18:30 e quando tento fazer um cadastro do mesmo médico inicio 21/01/2019 18:01 fim 21/01/2019 18:25 ele agenda normalmente.
A ideia é que o medico não faça duas consultas ao mesmo tempo, poderia me ajudar, acredito que o problema seja na varredura do between.

Answer (score 0):

User o [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) pra testar o que você falou funciona o indice.

drop table agendamento_medico; 
create table agendamento_medico 
(id int primary key , 
id_medico int, 
data timestamp);
create index idx_medico_agendamento on agendamento_medico (id_medico,data);
insert into agendamento_medico values(1,1,'2019-05-05 00:00:00');
insert into agendamento_medico values(2,1,'2019-05-05 01:00:00');
insert into agendamento_medico values(4,1,'2019-05-05 02:00:00');
insert into agendamento_medico values(5,1,'2019-05-05 03:00:00');
insert into agendamento_medico values(6,1,'2019-05-05 04:00:00');

explain 
select * from agendamento_medico where id_medico =  1 and data between '2019-05-05 02:00:00' and '2019-05-05 03:30:00'

desse jeito você consegue fazer um indice scan. notando que precisa do id do medico nessa tabela de agendamento_medico. é uma colecao de datas, não precisa data_inicio nem data_fim, já que não pode ocorrer colisão.

o esquema é quando voce vai inserir nessa tabela verifica se vai ocorrer colisão. que é o que eu presumo o que voce quer que não aconteça. dai vai gravar gera duas linhas, o indice vai funcionar. recomendo o h2 pra fazer essas coisas que é bem tranquilo.

estou saindo do primefaces - java , porque esse modelo data_inicio data_fim não enxergo ele como a maneira correta de expressar as datas associadas ao envento, porque esta se falando em hql o problema é no modelo de entidadae e não no primefaces.

acho que data_inicio e data_fim é a escala do evendo.. ou melhor escala do agendamento.

Answer (score -1):

o modelo é meio esquisito... porque em teoria você poderia utilizar um data e hora separado... ficaria where data = ? and hora = ? e você não teria o payload do between que pode ser oneroso dependendo do tamanho da tabela... e  data pode ser um formato sem timestamp... mas teria que dar um pensada melhor eu nao usaria timestamp e between quebraria data e hora ... o indice iria ficar bom... seria codigo do medico e data.

Comment: agora se ocorrer de o medico agendar a noite para uma operação até o dia seguinte... ai faz sentido usar o timestamp.

Comment: pensando aqui. utilizar uma duração padrão ;; data/hora e duração... fica mais fácil. a logica ia ser um pouco mais complexa porém ia ficar mais robusto. e tirar a concatenação com +"" ... isso é uma prática muito ruim. um StringBuilder deixa o hql mais elegante ou usar um named query.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelas observações, minha necessidade cabe somente a consultas.
Quanto a duração padrão que mencionou eu deixaria por exemplo: O campo datainicial para o usuario para ele selecionar um horario e setaria um valor de 30min a mais no datafim. 
Até ai tudo, mas no banco não daria na mesma ? ficariam duas datas separadas e eu utilizando um between para compara-las.

Comment: no banco nao daria na mesma... por exemplo Postgres você tem campos datetime, e hora ele variam de tamanho https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html em bytes. e o indice tb vai variar.. importante notar isso porque melhora a eficiencia. date hora e duração, ir pelo caminho timestamp é between. e usando date e time separado é sem between vou tentar montar um exemplo tem que ver se funciona em jpa o que estou te falando

Comment: isso ai... voce pode usar data/hora... sem problemas nenhum... https://thoughts-on-java.org/map-date-time-api-jpa-2-2/ data=${data} e hora... acho que fica melhor.